# jquery data attributes search with condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery's data attributes to search values from dropdown. Here below is the thing what i am doing here..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  // Default selected as blank value 
                $('#search_by_brand').prop('selectedIndex', "");
                
                // Our work page - Search by Brand 
                $('#search_by_brand').change(function() {
                  $('#search_by_channel').prop('selectedIndex', "");
                  $('#search_by_type').prop('selectedIndex', "");
               
                    var brand_value = $(this).val();
                    
                    if(brand_value != '')
                    {                    
                      $( ".filtr-container div" ).hide();                  
                      $( ".filtr-container div[data-brand='"+ brand_value + "']" ).show().children().show();   
                      $(".filtr-container").find(".mask").show();               
                      
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      $( ".filtr-container div" ).show();                  
                    } 


                    // getting the lenght of number of divs which are available .. 
                    var visible_divs = $('.filtr-container').children('div:visible').length;

                    if(visible_divs == 0)
                    {
                      $(".filtr-container").append('<p class="no_records text-center f-s-18 m-t-15 col-sm-12" style="padding: 300px 0px;">No Records Found</p>');                      
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      $( ".no_records" ).remove();
                    }


                    
                });


                // Default selected as blank value 
                $('#search_by_channel').prop('selectedIndex', "");
                
                // Our work page - Search by Product Channel 
                $('#search_by_channel').change(function() {

                  $('#search_by_brand').prop('selectedIndex', "");
                  $('#search_by_type').prop('selectedIndex', "");
               
                    var channel_value = $(this).val();                    
                    if(channel_value != '')
                    {                    
                      $( ".filtr-container div" ).hide();                  
                      $( ".filtr-container div[data-channel='"+ channel_value + "']" ).show().children().show();    

                      $(".filtr-container").find(".mask").show();              
                      
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      $( ".filtr-container div" ).show();                  
                    } 

                    // getting the lenght of number of divs which are available .. 
                    var visible_divs = $('.filtr-container').children('div:visible').length;

                    if(visible_divs == 0)
                    {
                      $(".filtr-container").append('<p class="no_records text-center f-s-18 m-t-15 col-sm-12" style="padding: 300px 0px;">No Records Found</p>');                      
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      $( ".no_records" ).remove();
                    }

                });



                // Default selected as blank value 
                $('#search_by_type').prop('selectedIndex', "");
                
                // Our work page - Search by Product Type 
                $('#search_by_type').change(function() {

                  $('#search_by_brand').prop('selectedIndex', "");
                  $('#search_by_channel').prop('selectedIndex', "");
               
                    var type_value = $(this).val();                    
                    if(type_value != '')
                    {                    
                      $( ".filtr-container div" ).hide();                  
                      $( ".filtr-container div[data-type='"+ type_value + "']" ).show().children().show();    

                      $(".filtr-container").find(".mask").show();              
                      
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      $( ".filtr-container div" ).show();                  
                    } 
                    
                    // getting the lenght of number of divs which are available .. 
                    var visible_divs = $('.filtr-container').children('div:visible').length;

                    if(visible_divs == 0)
                    {
                      $(".filtr-container").append('<p class="no_records text-center f-s-18 m-t-15 col-sm-12" style="padding: 300px 0px;">No Records Found</p>');                      
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      $( ".no_records" ).remove();
                    }

                });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-inline">
       <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label">Brand</label>
          
             <select class="form-control" id="search_by_brand" name="search_by_brand">
                 <option value="">Select Product Brand</option>
                 <option value="GLAM">GLAM</option>
                    <option value="PEDIGREE">PEDIGREE</option>
                    <option value="NESTLE">NESTLE</option>
                    <option value="HAVAIANAS">HAVAIANAS</option>
                    <option value="ROYAL CANIN">ROYAL CANIN</option>
                    <option value="EUKANUBA">EUKANUBA</option>
                </select>
        </div>
        
         <div class="form-group m-l-30">
         <label class="control-label">Channel</label>
          
             <select class="form-control" id="search_by_channel" name="search_by_channel">
                 <option value="">Select Product Channel</option>
                 <option value="Pharmacy">Pharmacy</option>
                    <option value="Pet">Pet</option>
                    <option value="Department Store">Department Store</option>
                    <option value="Vet">Vet</option>
                </select>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group m-l-30">
         <label class="control-label">Type</label>
          
             <select class="form-control" id="search_by_type" name="search_by_type">
                 <option value="">Select Product Type</option>
                 <option>Advertisement</option>
                    <option>Campaign</option>
                </select>
        </div>
      </form>
      
      

<div class="filtr-container">



        
          
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 filtr-item" data-brand="GLAM" data-channel="Vet" data-type="Advertisement">
                <div class="view-inner view-first text-center">  

                  <a href="http://localhost/5p_front/product/10">
                  
                    <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/yka2yx5/YHAm28h2j/glam_fb.jpg" height="20%" width="20%">                      
                      <div class="mask">
                         <p>
                            <span class="f-s-23">GLAM</span><br>
                            <span class="f-s-23 lobstar">Daily Care</span><br>
                            <span class="roboto-light">Vet</span><br>
                         </p>
                      </div>
                  
                  
                  </a> 
                  </div>
                <div class="filter-shadow"></div>
            </div>
        
          
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 filtr-item" data-brand="ROYAL CANIN" data-channel="Pet" data-type="Advertisement">
                <div class="view-inner view-first text-center">  

                  <a href="http://localhost/5p_front/product/9">
                  
                    <img src="http://www.royalcanin.com.au/extension/site_subsidiary_v3/design/subsidiary_v3/images/article/no-img-article.png" height="20%" width="20%">                      
                      <div class="mask">
                         <p>
                            <span class="f-s-23">ROYAL CANIN</span><br>
                            <span class="f-s-23 lobstar">Feline Gondola End</span><br>
                            <span class="roboto-light">Pet</span><br>
                         </p>
                      </div>
                  
                  
                  </a> 
                  </div>
                <div class="filter-shadow"></div>
            </div>
        
          
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 filtr-item" data-brand="HAVAIANAS" data-channel="Department Store" data-type="Advertisement">
                <div class="view-inner view-first text-center">  

                  <a href="http://localhost/5p_front/product/8">
                  
                    <img src="http://image.brazilianbikinishop.com/images/products/flipflop-havaianas-brasil-logo-green-0.jpg" height="20%" width="20%">                      
                      <div class="mask">
                         <p>
                            <span class="f-s-23">HAVAIANAS</span><br>
                            <span class="f-s-23 lobstar">Pop Up</span><br>
                            <span class="roboto-light">Department Store</span><br>
                         </p>
                      </div>
                  
                  
                  </a> 
                  </div>
                <div class="filter-shadow"></div>
            </div>
        
          
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 filtr-item" data-brand="NESTLE" data-channel="Pharmacy" data-type="Advertisement">
                <div class="view-inner view-first text-center">  

                  <a href="http://localhost/5p_front/product/7">
                  
                    <img src="http://www.indiantelevision.com/sites/drupal7.indiantelevision.co.in/files/images/mam-images/2016/04/18/mam%20financials.jpg" height="20%" width="20%">                      
                      <div class="mask">
                         <p>
                            <span class="f-s-23">NESTLE</span><br>
                            <span class="f-s-23 lobstar">Good Life</span><br>
                            <span class="roboto-light">Pharmacy</span><br>
                         </p>
                      </div>
                  
                  
                  </a> 
                  </div>
                <div class="filter-shadow"></div>
            </div>
        
          
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 filtr-item" data-brand="PEDIGREE" data-channel="Pet" data-type="Advertisement">
                <div class="view-inner view-first text-center">  

                  <a href="http://localhost/5p_front/product/6">
                  
                    <img src="https://www.petsworld.in/media/brands/6/pedigree2.jpg" height="20%" width="20%">                      
                      <div class="mask">
                         <p>
                            <span class="f-s-23">PEDIGREE</span><br>
                            <span class="f-s-23 lobstar">Cleaner gets you closer</span><br>
                            <span class="roboto-light">Pet</span><br>
                         </p>
                      </div>
                  
                  
                  </a> 
                  </div>
                <div class="filter-shadow"></div>
            </div>
        
          
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 filtr-item" data-brand="GLAM" data-channel="Pharmacy" data-type="Advertisement">
                <div class="view-inner view-first text-center">  

                  <a href="http://localhost/5p_front/product/5">
                  
                    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/06/GLAM_logo.png" height="20%" width="20%">                      
                      <div class="mask">
                         <p>
                            <span class="f-s-23">GLAM</span><br>
                            <span class="f-s-23 lobstar">Beauty Bar</span><br>
                            <span class="roboto-light">Pharmacy</span><br>
                         </p>
                      </div>
                  
                  
                  </a> 
                  </div>
                <div class="filter-shadow"></div>
            </div>
        



      </div>
```

As you can see in my demo that i am searching Products from Brand,Channel and Type. But i want to enable an ability to Advance Search the same thing with multiple dropdown.

For now it is searching only with one dropdown, i want an ability to search with multiple dropdown say for example, if i select Product Brand "GLAM" and Product Channel "Pharmacy" then only those records should come using "AND" condition or jquery or something like that ..

Same should apply to Product Type as well .. What should i do ?

Thanks

Comment: What did you try and what problem you ran into

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a class to all `select` elements and bind `change` using `class selector` as code is same for all `select elements`.

You can create `filters` based on values of `dropdown` and dynamically add `filters` if `value of dropdown` is `selected`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('.selectFilter').change(function () {

            var brand_value = $("#search_by_brand").val();
            var channel = $('#search_by_channel').val();
            var type = $("#search_by_type").val();
            var channelFilter = "";
            var typeFilter = "";
            var brand_valueFiltr = "";
            if (brand_value != '')
                brand_valueFiltr = "[data-brand='" + brand_value + "']";
            if (channel != '')
                channelFilter = "[data-channel='" + channel + "']";
            if (type != '')
                typeFilter = "[data-type='" + type + "']";


            $(".filtr-container div").hide();
            $(".filtr-container div" + brand_valueFiltr + channelFilter + typeFilter).show().children().show();
            $(".filtr-container").find(".mask").show();

            // getting the lenght of number of divs which are available .. 
            var visible_divs = $('.filtr-container').children('div:visible').length;

            if (visible_divs == 0) {
                $(".filtr-container").append('<p class="no_records text-center f-s-18 m-t-15 col-sm-12" style="padding: 300px 0px;">No Records Found</p>');
            }
            else {
                $(".no_records").remove();
            }
        });
    });
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/UvjnT/1470/) is jsfiddle